# How to get all attributes(visible on frontend) and their corresponding options of a product collection in Magento?

Tags: magento

Lets say, these are the attributes color and size.  Color has following options red, green and blue and size has following options small,medium and large.  Now, assume product collection has two products in it and one product is of red color and has size small and other one is of green color and has size medium.  So, I want output like below

- **Color**: red,green
- **Size**: small,medium

I do not want to fetch attribute list collection first and then iterate and match with it attributes of each and every product in collection because that would be very slow and memory consuming.

Comment: Assuming you have the product collection already, you can loop through the configurable attributes on each product and add them to an array to output as your example

Comment: @Robbie Averill - What if product collection has thousands of products. Then it would take lot of time. Can't it be done using a single SQL query. Same thing is achieved in layered navigation where only those attributes and options are shown that belongs to product collection in use.

Comment: Hi Vineet, yes that's a good question but you must always consider load time when dealing with that many entities. What do you need to do this for? How often will it run? You could do this with SQL but it would involve many table joins

Comment: @Robbie Averill - I am working on a functionality in which I have to create layered navigation type filters for bundle products' options(child products).  It would be AJAX based so it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged how layered navigation works in Magento and based on that I came up with below mentioned solution.

```
try{
        //Get product collection and apply filter to it if any. Here I am applying dummy color filter
        $prodCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('color',array('in' => array(3,4))); //change this filter ad per your need

        $prodCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId());

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($prodCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($prodCollection); 

        $setId = 4; //default attribute set id. change this as pre your need. You can also make this an array

        //Get catalog attribute collection of some attribute sets.
        $attrCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
        $attrCollection
            ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
            ->setAttributeSetFilter($setId)
            ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');

        $attrCollection->addIsFilterableFilter(); //Check if attributes are filterable or not

        $attrCollection->load();

        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $filterResourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/layer_filter_attribute');

        //Apply filter to product collection, if any
        if(1){ //Check if any filters are applied on product collection from query string (?color=4&size=8)
            foreach($attrCollection as $attribute){

                //For now just for testing purpose, I have hardcoded it to work only for single attribute i.e. color
                if($attribute->getAttributeCode() != 'color'){
                    continue;
                }

                //I am assuming color filter is applied twice 
                $filterName = 'color';
                $filterId = 92;
                $filterVal = array(3,4);      

                $tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_fa';

                $conditions = array(
                    "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
                    $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
                    $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $prodCollection->getStoreId()),
                    $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.value IN (?)", $filterVal)
                );

                $prodCollection->getSelect()->join(
                    array($tableAlias => $filterResourceModel->getMainTable()),
                    implode(' AND ', $conditions),
                    array()
                );

            }
        }


        //Iterate each attribute one by one. For now just for testing purpose, I have hardcoded it to work only for single attribute i.e. color
        foreach($attrCollection as $attribute){
            if($attribute->getAttributeCode() != 'color'){
                continue;
            }

            //find attributes options
            $options = $attribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();

            // clone select from collection with filters
            $select = clone $prodCollection->getSelect();
            // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
            $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

            $tableAlias = sprintf('%s_idx', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
            $conditions = array(
                "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
                $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
                $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),  //$filter->getStoreId()
            );

            $select
                ->join(
                    array($tableAlias => $filterResourceModel->getMainTable()),
                    join(' AND ', $conditions),
                    array('value', 'count' => new Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)")))
                ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");


            $optionsCount = $connection->fetchPairs($select);


            $data = array();
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if (is_array($option['value'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($option['value'])) {
                    $data[] = array(
                            'label' => $option['label'],
                            'value' => $option['value'],
                            'count' => isset($optionsCount[$option['value']]) ? $optionsCount[$option['value']] : 0,
                        );
                }

            }  
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); die('<><>');
          }        
    }catch(Exception $e){

    }
```